# @view when both sides of equation are array slice in Julia

Tags: julia

I tried to optimize my code with @view. But I don't know If I should use @view if array slice is in left-hand side.

At first, I knew @view could reduce cost when used in the right-hand side like this :

```
a = @view b[:]
```

But if the left-hand side is also array slice. I don't know the meaning of @view.
For example, see the code below

```
using BenchmarkTools
a = ones(50,100)
b = zeros(50,50)
@benchmark a[:,1:25] = b[:,1:25]
@benchmark a[:,1:25] = @view b[:,1:25]
```

The second allocation with @view is faster. And this operation is more like a copy because if I change element in b, a won't change.

So my question is what is the meaning of @view in this case? Should I use @view in this situation?
Why I change elements in a, b won't change?

The second allocation seems faster in this case, but I found using @view might slow down my program when used in a larger case.

Answer (score 3):

`a[:,1:25] = b[:,1:25]` creates an array for `b[:,1:25]` and then copies element by element `a[:,1:25] = @view b[:,1:25]` skips the first part leading to no allocations and better performance.